# Trying to generate a DataFrame in a specific format using crosstab, pivot_table, or groupby and not getting the desired result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pretty new to `pandas` and trying to generate a table from a `DataFrame` in a specific format. There seems to be a number of options, but having trouble getting the format using `crosstab`, `pivot_table`, or `groupby`.

The oversimplified CSV looks like the following that is being converted to a `DataFrame`:

```
| code | company | user | all | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | price |
| ---- | ------- | ---- | --- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| ABC  | 1       | 123  | x   | x     |       | x     | 50    |
| ABC  | 1       | 456  | x   |       | x     |       | 70    |
| ABC  | 1       | 789  | x   | x     | x     |       | 90    |
| ABC  | 2       | 098  | x   |       |       | x     | 55    |
| ABC  | 2       | 765  | x   | x     |       |       | 75    |
| ABC  | 2       | 432  | x   | x     | x     | x     | 95    |
```

The table I'm trying to generate:

```
| code | company | cat   | price_n | price_avg |
| ---- | ------- | ----- | ------- | --------- |
| ABC  | 1       | all   | 3       | 70        |
| ABC  | 1       | cat_1 | 2       | 70        |
| ABC  | 1       | cat_2 | 2       | 80        |
| ABC  | 1       | cat_3 | 1       | 50        |
| ABC  | 2       | all   | 3       | 75        |
| ABC  | 2       | cat_1 | 2       | 85        |
| ABC  | 2       | cat_2 | 1       | 95        |
| ABC  | 2       | cat_3 | 2       | 75        |
```

I can think of a way to achieve this using a loop, but seeing if there is native way for `pandas` to handle it. For the first thing that comes to mind is doing something like:

```
def crunch_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    for var in ['all', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3']:
        df.groupby(['code', 'company', var]).agg(
            price_n=('user', 'count'),
            price_avg=('price', 'mean')
```

`UNION` (whatever the `pandas` equivalent might be) the data together and sort.

Suggestions for a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame (later update it with your current datasource)
data = {
    'code': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
    'company': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'user': [123, 456, 789, 98, 765, 432],
    'all': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
    'cat_1': ['x', '', 'x', '', 'x', 'x'],
    'cat_2': ['', 'x', 'x', '', '', 'x'],
    'cat_3': ['x', '', '', 'x', '', 'x'],
    'price': [50, 70, 90, 55, 75, 95]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Drop NaN values in the 'indicator' column (I suggest you don't leave them like that try to replace them by N/A or -1 depending on the type)
df = df.dropna(subset=['all', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3'], how='all')

# Group by 'code', 'company', 'cat' columns, and aggregate the data
result = df.melt(id_vars=['code', 'company', 'user', 'price'],
                 value_vars=['all', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3'],
                 var_name='cat',
                 value_name='indicator')

result = result.groupby(['code', 'company', 'cat']).agg(
    price_n=('indicator', lambda x: x.eq('x').sum()),
    price_avg=('price', lambda x: x[result['indicator'] == 'x'].mean())
).reset_index()

# Sort the result by 'code', 'company', and 'cat' 'you may need to add other columns if needed)
result = result.sort_values(['code', 'company', 'cat']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)
```

Result :

```
      code       company      cat        price_n   price_avg
0     ABC        1            all        3         70
1     ABC        1          cat_1        2         70
2     ABC        1          cat_2        2         80
3     ABC        1          cat_3        1         50
4     ABC        2            all        3         75
5     ABC        2          cat_1        2         85
6     ABC        2          cat_2        1         95
7     ABC        2          cat_3        2         75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try (assuming this initial 0-1 dataframe):

```py
  code  company  user  all  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  price
0  ABC        1   123    1      1      0      1     50
1  ABC        1   456    1      0      1      0     70
2  ABC        1   789    1      1      1      0     90
3  ABC        2    98    1      0      0      1     55
4  ABC        2   765    1      1      0      0     75
5  ABC        2   432    1      1      1      1     95
```

---

```py
df[["all", "cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row[["all", "cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3"]] * row["price"], axis=1
)

df = df.drop(columns=["user", "price"])

df = (
    df.set_index(["code", "company"])
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=[0, 1, 2])
    .agg(
        (
            ("price_n", lambda x: (x != 0).sum()),
            ("price_avg", lambda x: x[(x != 0)].mean()),
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "cat"})
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  code  company    cat  price_n  price_avg
0  ABC        1    all        3       70.0
1  ABC        1  cat_1        2       70.0
2  ABC        1  cat_2        2       80.0
3  ABC        1  cat_3        1       50.0
4  ABC        2    all        3       75.0
5  ABC        2  cat_1        2       85.0
6  ABC        2  cat_2        1       95.0
7  ABC        2  cat_3        2       75.0
```